# How to make a simple script that increases a number character by 1

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, linux-networking

I have to add a single command for MANY vlans, and wondering if I can generate a simple text file somehow? Then I can simply paste the text file into the network switch and it will add the needed lines.

Basically, this single command:

```
ip dhcp-relay 10.32.150.129 10.32.50.1 enable
```

will need to be executed consecutively, increasing with the .50 by 1.

So it would be like, .50, .51, .52, .53...

so it would generate a file like:

```
ip dhcp-relay 10.32.150.129 10.32.50.1 enable
ip dhcp-relay 10.32.151.129 10.32.51.1 enable
ip dhcp-relay 10.32.152.129 10.32.52.1 enable
```

etc...

here's my  script

```
#!/bin/bash

if xy=50

    echo "ip dhcp-relay 10.32.150.129 10.32.50.1 enable" >> pastethisinswitch.txt
    echo "ip dhcp-relay 10.32.1xy.129 10.32.xy.1 enable" >> pastethisinswitch.txt

    xy+1

    until xy=99
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really simple as you describe it:

```
for k in {50..99}; do echo ip dhcp-relay 10.32.1$k.129 10.32.$k.1 enable; done > pastethisinswitch.txt
```

but it will only scale up to 99 that way.

You can scale it up to 254 like so:

```
for k in {50..154}; do echo ip dhcp-relay 10.32.$(expr 100 + $k).129 10.32.$k.1 enable; done > pastethisinswitch.txt
```

Your original attempt would look somewhat like this in working form:

```
#!/bin/bash

k=50

while [ "$k" -lt "100" ];
do
    echo "ip dhcp-relay 10.32.1$k.129 10.32.$k.1 enable " >> outfile
    k=$((k+1))
done
```

but many alternative forms would also work.

Comment: ahhh that one liner is beautiful! I'm still trying to understand while and if loops, I see you are using test with -lt meaning less than right? the 'trick' or part i see is k=$((k+1)) . is there a reason for the double brackets? its best practice right?

Comment: The double brackets are a bash syntax thing to turn on arithmetic context. Unlike with most other programming languages, `k=$k+1` wouldn't work just like that and you have to force the "math mode" with this. And yes, `-lt` means "less then" and it could have been written with `(())` expressions as well.